# Can we install codecoverage.exe without Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

In VS 2010, we can install vs_profiler independently on different box where Visual Studio is not available. And we can perform steps like instrumentation and code coverage.

Do we have same feasibility in VS 2013? I was looking for separate installer for Dynamic Code Coverage but did not found any.

Answer (score 0):

To install VSTest.Console.exe, install the NuGet package Microsoft.TestPlatform.15.9.0.  To install CodeCoverage.exe, install the NuGet package Microsoft.TestPlatform.15.9.0.

Answer (score -1):

My original post:

> I'm not sure if you have found the answer for your question, but I happen to encountered the same problem, and I found that Test Agent from Microsoft contains the CodeCoverage.exe. You can find the installer here: 
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750

It looks like my original post was considered inappropriate by the others here, because it is a "link-only" post. So I'll try to explain it here. I just try to help people that might find the same problem as me. The link that I provided is not answer, it is Microsoft download center where you can find the installer to solve this problem. If you still find it inappropriate, feel free to delete it.

Just like Kartik here, I need to use codecoverage.exe to get test coverage information without installing Visual Studio, because this need to be done on a build server. I've tried to search here on stackoverflow, but I only found this post, where there were no answers provided.

After spending some time looking for answer, I found that Test Agent for VS 2013 contains the file in question here, the codecoverage.exe.

So to answer the question, yes you can install codecoverage.exe without installing Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, by installing Test Agent for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. You can find the installer [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750) or google it.

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?

Comment: The link is to Microsoft download center. The solution that I found working is to install the Microsoft Test Agent. After successfully installing it, you will have codecoverage.exe installed on your machine.